# Counters on a Chessboard (BMO 2010/11)

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, contest-math

> Isaac has a large supply of counters, and places one in each of the $1 \times 1$ squares of an $8 \times 8$ chessboard. Each counter is either red, white, or blue. A particular pattern of colored counters is called an *arrangement*. Determine whether there are more arrangements which contain an even number of red counters, or more arrangements which contain an odd number of red counters. (Note that 0 is an even number.)

I solved this problem using a recurrence relation: laying out the chessboard squares in a straight line, counting the number of ways to do it for any number of squares, and coming up with closed-form formulae:
$$e_n = \frac{3^n + 1}{2} \\
o_n = \frac{3^n - 1}{2}$$
where $n$ is the number of squares, $e_n$ counts even reds, $o_n$ counts odd reds.

However, the two quantities differ only by 1. This seems significant to me, because I cannot intuitively see why: I tried to come up with a 'bijection' sort of approach to the problem, which perhaps would say "for all arrangements with an even number of red counters, there is a unique one with an odd number of red counters, but hey, we have *precisely one* we can't account for". I tried doing this by various means, like flipping colors, counting sub-boards, etc. but didn't get anything. *Can you find a bijection/mapping which makes intuitive sense?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a fixed placement of **white** counters on the chessboard; the remaining squares must be occupied by red or blue counters.

**Claim:** For a given placement of white counters, there are just as many arrangements with an even number of red counters as with an odd number of red counters.

**Proof:** Pick a square that is not occupied by a white counter. Flipping the counter on that square between red and blue gives the desired  bijection.

**OOPS!!** There is one exception! If **ALL** the squares are occupied by white counters, then there is only one possible arrangement, and it has an **EVEN** number of red counters!!

Comment: Ok, so I flipped a red counter to make it a blue counter giving me another arrangement. However, there are plenty of initial arrangements, on which I can flip a counter to get the same new arrangement! How can I be sure that it is a bijection?

Comment: Maybe you overlooked that the bijection is defined for a ***fixed*** placement of white counters, and a ***fixed square*** (depending on the placement of white counters) is flipped to make the bijection.

Comment: Right, you're flipping a fixed counter (in a defined position), unique for every arrangement of white counters. Thanks!

Comment: It's basically the **same** as the way you prove that, for $n\gt0$, exactly half of the bit strings of length $n$ have an even number of ones.

Comment: So for bit strings, you flip, say, the last bit; in this question, you can flip the topmost nonwhite counter in the leftmost row or something like that; and the general approach will work whenever you can have some order on the individual pieces you're counting?

Comment: It's really the same thing. The square array has nothing to do with it, you might as well arrange the counters in a straight line. For a fixed arrangement of white counters, the arrangement of red and blue counters **is** just a bitstring.